# Yarn Berry - Run a Node Script Directly

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, yarnpkg

Yarn berry (v2) got rid of node_modules (which I really love) by introducing pnp. However, scripts executed by node directly don't understand pnp modules, so you have to use yarn to run such a script.

Is there some way (e.g. a require script like ts-node provides) so that I can still use node to launch my script that requires pnp modules?

Background is that I want to configure the Mocha Sidebar extension for VS Code to support pnp. I can add configure node options there and specify files that are required automatically.

Comment: Also, I don't mean `yarn node myscript.js`. Ideally I want to keep node as the binary and just use a require script.

Answer (score 0):

That's the (undocumented) solution:

```js
require(".pnp.js").setup();
```