# yarn berry run how to run installed packages

Tags: yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2

I see with yarn berry I get the plug'n'play feature instead of node_modules/

I couldn't find anything to suggest it supports running from installed packages.

For example with npm a workflow might be to run the installed version of webpack:

```
$ npm install --save-dev webpack
$ node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack ...
```

A globally installed webpack might not be the same version.  Worse yet, during Docker deployment, I get what's installed locally, the only node and npm are available globally.  I thought I can do a `preinstall` script that does `npm install -g yarn; yarn set version berry` but then I'm not sure how to do `webpack`, `jest`, `babel`, etc, and the thought that I should have to install them all globally during the same `preinstall` hackaround seems like several steps backwards.

Is there some way to run from locally-installed packages that I'm missing?

I saw this possibly related question - [Yarn Berry - Run a Node Script Directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61475926/yarn-berry-run-a-node-script-directly)

But the answer there seems a bit off the point - I'm not running any js, I'm trying to type in a package.json script, i.e. something that can run from the shell.

Comment: Ok will try that thank you @josh-wilson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use `yarn run <bin>` (or simply `yarn <bin>`)? If you are in a repository set to use yarn berry, that will run any package bin file.

`yarn node <file>` will run any `.js` file with Plug n' Play set up. No need to install those dependencies globally, except for maybe yarn classic.

Comment: thanks that was right, I was relying on the cli help that didn't clue me in very well

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do `yarn some-bin` and kept getting:

```
Couldn't find a script named "some-bin".
```

I eventually figured out it was because the package that provides `some-bin` is installed inside a workspace and not at the root of my project. So instead I had to run:

```
yarn workspace my-workspace some-bin
```

And that worked.